# Applescript - get note from Notes.app

Tags: applescript

can someone explain this weird behaviour to me? I am trying to get a note named "TEST" but even when I run this command:

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    set theName to get name of the first note
    display dialog theName
    set theNote to the note whose name is theName
end tell
```

Dialog will correctly display name (that is a "TEST").
But this code resulted with an error: "Can’t get note whose name = \"TEST\"."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the "whose name is" and you should get what you're after.

e.g,

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    set theName to get name of the first note
    display dialog theName
    set theNote to the note theName
end tell
```